# Using a sequence to prove a subspace has no interior points

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I am working on this problem:

**Prove explicitly that $L^2[0, 1]$ as vector subspace of $L^1[0, 1]$ has no interior points**

**Suggestion:** It is enough to show that for each element of $L^2[0, 1]$ it is possible to construct a sequence of elements belonging to $L^1[0; 1] \setminus L^2[0, 1]$ which converges in $L^1[0, 1] $ to that element

**Can someone please explain the logic of the suggestion?** I don't follow it. I know points in the closure of a set can be characterized as limit of sequence, but for interior points all I know is the definition that says: "x is an interior point of a set S if there exist an open ball contained in that set". I was trying to  prove that the suggestio follows from this definiton but not luck
I already have the solution of the problem, but I don't understant it, because I don't understand the suggestion that they have implemented.
Can someone shed some some light?

Comment: The hint is a fair bit stronger than necessary. A subspace of a normed vector space has empty interior if and only if it is a proper subspace (this is a nice simple exercise to prove). Thus, all you need is a function in $L^1[0, 1]$ that isn't in $L^2[0, 1]$, and you'll be done.

Comment: @user847970 does the proof of that proposition has to do with the suggestion?. Anyway, any idea why the suggestion is true?

Comment: My suggestion has nothing at all to do with the given suggestion. The point I'm making is that the given suggestion isn't a good suggestion. As soon as you find even one point of the sequence belonging to $L^1[0, 1] \setminus L^2[0, 1]$, you have enough information to conclude the conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is an interior point of $L^{2}$ in $L^{1}$. Then there exists an  open ball $B(f,r)$ contained in $L^{2}$. Now suppose we can find a sequence $(f_n)$ in $L^{1}\setminus L^{2}$ converging to $f$. Then $f_n \in B(f,r)$ for $n$ sufficiently large. But this is a contradiction because $f_n \in B(f,r) \subseteq L^{2}$ and $f_n \notin L^{2}$.

Comment: There are two suppositions you are making. I think the contradiction is for the second one, therefore we cannot find a sequence in $L^1 \setminus L^2$. From this how do I refute that $f$ is an interior point?

Comment: I am picturing this in $R^2$ with the usual metric to make sense of it graphically, but how can I make sure it is true in  this abstract $L^2$ and $L^1$ function space? Do I have to deal with the integrals definind the norms? I tried that but got nowhere

Comment: What they are saying is that, **taking existence  of $(f_n)$ for granted** we can prove that there are no interior points. So you cannot question the existence of $(f_n)$ here. The contradiction I have obtained is for the assumption that $f$ is an interior point. @mathlover

Comment: Can the statement "then$ f_n \in B(f,r)$ for $n$ sufficiently large" be developed in more detail? I am trying to use inequalities to get to this conclusion ,but I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: $f_n \to f$ implies that $\|f_n-f\|_1 <r$ for $n$ sufficiently large. @mathlover